# Exiting out of for loop and returning when at the end of a file

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to loop through a file and return every line:

```
for i in master_file:
        columns = re.split('\s{2,}', i)
        last_name = columns[1]
        print(last_name)
```

If I replace `print` with `return` it will only return `columns[1]` for the first line, but I want to return it for all the lines. So I can use that info elsewhere in my function.

Comment: return will terminate your loop, you need a different approach to this particular request like yield

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case you need to `yield` the value and not `return` it:

```
for i in master_file:
        columns = re.split('\s{2,}', i)
        last_name = columns[1]
        yield last_name
```

Complete sample:

```
def readLastNames ():
    for i in master_file:
            columns = re.split('\s{2,}', i)
            last_name = columns[1]
            yield last_name

for last_name in readLastNames ():
    print (last_name)
```

---

Very rough explanation: `yield` passes the parameters and the **control** back to the calling context, perserves the state of the called context and resumes then from there.

Comment: I've tried using yield before, I keep getting this error: `<generator object query at 0x0282A378>`

Comment: @Amon This is not an error. It is a generator. You need to consume it. Something like the last two lines of my second snippet. `for x in myGeneratorFunction(): print(x)`.

Comment: Oh my bad, it worked indeed. Can I use this method to create variables  (like `last_name`) that I can use inside the function?

Comment: What name (variable) to assign to each yielded value is your choice.

Comment: So I have to use something like those last two lines right? What I want is to have different variables represent columns[1],  columns[2] etc.. Then do something else with that variable, rather than just print it out

Comment: @Amon Process it as normal: `for x in generator(): doWhatEverYouWantWith (x)`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `return`, use [yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)

It's like a return but it keeps the position in the iterable.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a list comprehension,

```
return [re.split('\s{2,}', line, 2)[1] for line in master_file]
```